# Providing a Generic to Mock

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, moq

I am attempting to generalize some test code in a solution with an MVC project. Because we're writing the same test for each controller, my thought was I could use generics to make it so only one test was needed.

Unfortunately, I'm currently getting the error: `Error  1   The type 'TRepo' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Moq.Mock<T>'`

Here's the relevant code. I can provide more if needed.

TestBase.cs

```
public class TestBase<TController, TObject, TRepo>
where TController : IRMCController<TObject>
where TRepo : IRMCRepository
{
    public Mock<TRepo> Repo { get; set; }
}
```

CompaniesTest.cs

```
public class CompaniesTest : TestBase<CompaniesController, Company, ICompanyRepository>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Moq, the `Mock<T>` class has a `class` constraint on its generic type. Here's how it's defined:

```
public class Mock<T> : Mock where T : class
```

so if you intend to use this in your class you must define the same `class` constraint in addition to the `IRMCRepository`:

```
public class TestBase<TController, TObject, TRepo>
    where TController : IRMCController<TObject>
    where TRepo : class, IRMCRepository

{
    public Mock<TRepo> Repo { get; set; }
}
```

Now your code's gonna compile. That's basic [`generic constraints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) in C#.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it when I get home. I had thought it might have been Mock<T> but I forgot to look.

Comment: Thank you, Darin! After some other tweaking, I got it to work. Much appreciated!